# 'Checkline' validation error while Perforce submit

Tags: perforce

I am trying to add image files in my perforce depot. These files are adding properly using :
p4 add

But getting checkline validation error while p4 submit:
'CheckLine' validation failed:
    Your submission has been rejected because the following files
    have line ending errors

Not getting what is going wrong. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Mark your files, or your file type, as binary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'CheckLine' is a trigger that your administrator has installed in your server; if that is so, your administrator can help you understand what local policy your submit is not adhering to.